# How do I make my layout (which is inside a tab linearlayout, take up the whole screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I have a pretty strange issue. So, I have a base tab layout which helps navigation between different activities and fragment. However, some of the layouts (esp fragment layouts) seem to be cut off exposing activities in the background.

Any idea why it could be doing this?
Here's the code for the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nav_back_btn"
            style="@style/Button.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/back"
            android:tint="@color/black"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_edit_button"
            style="@style/Body1RegRightBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_edit"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/profile_pic_container"
                layout="@layout/item_profile_pic" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fullName"
                    style="@style/Headline3CenterBlack"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Chronicle"
                    tools:text="Angela Heely" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/companyName"
                    style="@style/Body2RegCenterGrey"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fullName"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Cardinal Dev Agency" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/home_location"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/home_location"
                    style="@style/Body1RegRightGrey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                    tools:text="My Home location" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/push_notifications"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/push_notification_switch"
                    style="@style/Color1SwitchStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_settings_separator" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reset_password"
                    style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/reset_password"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/reset_password_chevron"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/brownish_grey" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/legal_terms"
                    style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/eula"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/legal_terms_chevron"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/brownish_grey" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_settings_separator" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorColor"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/optionLogout"
                    style="@style/Body1RegCenterRed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/sign_out" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/optionVersion"
            style="@style/Caption1RegCenterGrey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Build v. 0.0.1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for the tab base container layout: (Please note the actual screen content is displayed in the linearlayout titled : dynamicContent below)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"

>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:translationZ="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Matching"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/matching"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/watchList"
                android:text="Watchlist"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/rates"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Rates"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/deals"
                android:text="Deals"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/listing"
                android:text="Listing"/>


        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicContent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried many options including fitsystemwindows, commenting out scrollview and other solutions suggested on stackoverflow,  but not luck. Any ideas how to go about this one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `android:fillViewport="true"` in the scrollview

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, the above doesnt seem to work for nestedacrollview, any idea why?

Comment: If I could see the code snippet, I might be able to help

Comment: here;s the entire layout, the submit button at the bottom is supposed to have a space between add guest and itself, but it gets compressed somehow and submit button moves all the way up : https://pastebin.com/7djrcFxr

Comment: Two Points:
(1) Since Parent view of submit button is Relative layout. Put a flag 
`android:layout_below="@+id/main_register_layout"`
to put it under the Linear Layout
(2) I am not sure, if it is on purpose, but you have
`android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"`
in your Coordinator Layout